# MongoDB Benchmark with write-intensive on geo-indexed DB

Tags: index, mongodb, spatial, benchmark

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 on AWS RDS to store geo information into an indexed table of points.

My data is write-oriented, meaning that I write nearly 1,000 points per each geo search query.

I am considering some scaling solutions, and MongoDB seems like a natural choice because it's mature, scales up well, and [supports geo indexes out of the box](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/).

Is there any reliable and recent benchmark that compares MongoDB performance to other SQL and NoSQL solutions, preferably under write-intensive scenarios?

Comment: Since no benchmark will resemble your use case, it is safe to say: No. I'd strongly suggest setting up a sharded MongoDB cluster for testing purposes and find out with your data and your use cases.

Comment: EnterpriseDB has created a benchmark suite especially for this purpose: http://blogs.enterprisedb.com/2014/09/24/postgres-outperforms-mongodb-and-ushers-in-new-developer-reality/ You could also have a look at [Postgres-XL](http://www.postgres-xl.org/) or [Postgres-XC](http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/) both allow for horizontal scaling.

Answer (score 2):

i have used PostGIS for over a decade now and I can tell you for sure that there is no match for it in the NoSQL world.

how many rows do you have? how large is the thing? Mongo is definitely not going to make you happy. I am pretty sure you did something fishy on the PostgreSQL side to even consider using Mongo. Let us fix it ...

Comment: I am quite happy with it. The problem is that it has a problem scaling beyond a single machine, albeit a very large one.

Comment: in a simple setup yes. how much data do you have?

Comment: Suppose that I have too much data for a single instance, and I would like to scale to a setting without a single point of failure in which multiple nodes can be queried.

Comment: i would shard data. maybe using PL/proxy or something of the sort. but, before that it would be necessary to really see what is going on. most setups can nicely go with some simple streaming replicas. the largest geo data system i had in hands was 20 TB. you really got to collect a LOT of data to get there ...